# Time complexity n^2

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Is this O(N^2) or O(nlogn). Isnt it n^2 when there are nested loops?

```
int a[], N;
int f1(){ int i, j, sum=0;
    for (i=1;; i=2*i)
    {
        If (i>=N)  return sum;
        for (j=1; j<2*i;j++) sum+=a[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is `O(N log N)` as the outer loop is doubling the value of `i` in every iteration. So the complexity of outer loop is `O(log N)` instead of `O(N)`.

If you had `i++` or similar instead of `i=2*i` then the time complexity of two loops would have been `O(n^2)`.

Edit: this is a simplified analysis. Please see the [answer from R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55488267/377953) for more rigorous analysis.

Comment: Sorry but that is not correct. Doubling i doesn't make it n log n. It is something in between of n^2 and n log n.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this O(N^2) or O(nlogn).

It is neither.

> Isnt it n^2 when there are nested loops?

That is true when you iterate over the items linearly. That is not true in your case.

In your case ...

The values of `i` are: 1 2 4 8 16 ... N

The inner loop is executed 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 ... N times.

That is a geometric series. The sum of a geometric series is `a(1 - r^n)/(1 - r)`.

In your case, `a` is `2`, `r` is `2`, and `n` is `log2(N)` (log with base 2). Hence, the sum, after some simplification, is `2*2^(log2(N))`, which is same as `2*N`.

i.e your algorithmic complexity is `O(N)`.

Thanks are due to @LedHead for correcting the error in the initial post.

Comment: This is more rigorous analysis than my simple one. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the chart?

Comment: @gameon67, I used excel and pasted the text from there.

Comment: I think since the log is in the exponent you should be more careful about which log base you're using. In this case you want log2 not log_e. Then the whole thing reduces to O(N), whereas you have O(2^log_e(N)) = O(2^(log_e(2)*log2(N))) = O(N^log_e(2)) = O(N^0.301).